# (libgdx)how render method works?hiding begin batch draw

Tags: arrays, libgdx, render

How do you preload sprite batch for render method? you see i made 2 rectangle with same x,y axis. the 2 rectangles spawn 1 by 1 each second according to random number. (Example Random = 2, spawn rectangle2 and move downwards. delay . random = 1 spawn rectangle1 and move downwards.....)

so i add texture to the rectangle, and when program starts it spawn the 2 rectangles simultaneously together only for the first spawn. the next other spawn follow the random number.

Since i cant post images yet because of low reputation.:

This first image is when the game starts, so im assuming the render method starts also. So you can see the spritebatch is being drawn for first time(so they overlapped each other)
https://24.media.tumblr.com/cb0883c10b61411c5fbab54c0cf06111/tumblr_n1fertpAiv1qf52u7o1_500.png

Next image is the game proceeding normally.

https://24.media.tumblr.com/fd42c018d68fa675b21b16f1daf478dc/tumblr_n1fertpAiv1qf52u7o2_500.png

My question is refering to the first image. How can we hide that overlap image? because the spritebatch must be rendered for the first time thats why it is overlapping.

Comment: I did not understand the problem...

Comment: Sorry i rewrite the question. i can provide images if you still dont understand.

Comment: What is your question then? I don't get what you want to do.

Comment: I added image link and rewrote the question. Please assist me again.